# Call event after sorting in JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

#### Current Problem

---

In relearning jQuery/jQueryUI, I'm trying to call an event on an element after sorting it.  This is probably relatively simple to do since jQuery has many ways to implement callbacks.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('ul').addClass('list-unstyled');
  $('.sortable').sortable({
    revert: true,
    connectWith: ".sortable"
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  margin: .8rem 2rem !important;
}

li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div>div {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

body {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.sortable {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sortable>div:hover {
  background: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-Bxxp5LTCU2v12w2d0kxKb0vt5F4EgtrzcJKJSR3Xxio=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="sortable">
  <div>
    <ul class="1">
      <li>test 1</li>
      <li>test 2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul class="2">
      <li>test 3</li>
      <li>test 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="sortable">
  <div>
    <ul class="3">
      <li>test 7</li>
      <li>test 8</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul class="4">
      <li>test 9</li>
      <li>test 0</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

So let's say I move the 3/4 list.  I want to issue a callback (to change the background or the font size) after the element is finished moving.

#### Edit(s)

---

- **20101019-1145EST:** I think I need to be more clear.  I'm trying to call the event on a particular element that is sorted.  I guess I might be able to use the `sort`/`change` function, but shouldn't there be a conditional involved?  This involves more than adding a class, the eventual function I plan to attach will perform some AJAX as well as some calculations.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use the `stop` event of the `sortable` plugin.

> This event is triggered when sorting
>   has stopped.

In your example

```
$('.sortable')
    .sortable({
       revert       : true,
       connectWith  : ".sortable",
       stop         : function(event,ui){ /* do whatever here */ }
    });
```

Comment: that almost works, now how to limit this to a particular element

Comment: @vol7ron, `ui.item` inside the callback function holds the element that was moved, so perhaps you can work with that.. what exactly you want to limit ?

Comment: I'm working on centering a datepicker that can be dragged and dropped. Using the forumla: `(dp.parent.width - dp.width)/2`.  Eventually, I will include what columns are okay to resize in, and what ones should just be left/right justified.  There may be an easier way to do this, but I'm working with a multi-column layout.

Comment: `ui.item.find('.2')` seems to do what i need for traversal, the stop() function also does what I need.  -- I just know how inefficient this is going to be, though.

Comment: one other quick question: does `ui` have an object that defines the destination object?  Example, I have two '.sortable's above.  Is there a way to see what container it was dropped in?

Comment: @vol7ron, you can have the opposite functionality, you can use the `receive: function(event,ui)` event of a droppable element, and then you have access to `ui.sender`

Comment: @Gaby, yeah I was hoping to trigger an event on a particular list when something is inserted into it.  Something like check the inserted object and if its a particular element then perform some action.

Answer (score 2):

A list of events for the jquery ui sortable plugin can be found here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#events

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the events can be found here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

I'm guessing you would want to use the `sort` or the `change` event.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {   
    $('#sortable').sortable( { 
        revert    : true,
        connectWith  : ".sortable",
        stop     : function(event,ui){ 
              //write ur function here
        }
    });
});
```