# Automatically save data when using Jquery drag & drop without a button press

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Hi I have been googling this for an answer to my issue but i cannot seem to get the right answer so here I am hoping you lovely bunch can help me out.

I have a gridview in asp.net, using jquery i have managed to make the grid drag and droppable, as in you can reorder the rows via the D&D features. Currently I have an update button that allows users to save the order in a db (via server side code behind does really matter what VB, C). This all works great but what would be even better would be if as the row is dropped it calls a server side routine which saves the row orders (all the rows) rather than getting the users to push a button.

I have tried many things, one example i had was an ajax call however i cannot get any of this to work, does anyone else know how I can make changes straight to the db on a drag and drop without pressing a button.

My original Drag & Drop gridview Jquery

```
$x(function () {
           $x("[id*=gv]").sortable({
                items: 'tr:not(tr:first-child)',
                cursor: 'pointer',
                axis: 'y',
                dropOnEmpty: false,
                start: function (e, ui) {
                    ui.item.addClass("selected");
                },
                stop: function (e, ui) {
                    ui.item.removeClass("selected");
                },
                receive: function (e, ui) {
                    $x(this).find("tbody").append(ui.item);
                }
            });
        });
```

I then thought i could capture what has changed via the stop function so then added

```
$x(function () {
               $x("[id*=gv]").sortable({
                    items: 'tr:not(tr:first-child)',
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    axis: 'y',
                    dropOnEmpty: false,
                    start: function (e, ui) {
                        ui.item.addClass("selected");
                    },
                    stop: function (e, ui) {
                        ui.item.removeClass("selected");
                    var code = ui.item.attr("ID");
                    var pos = ui.item.index();
                    var options = {
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "mywebform.aspx/MyMethod",
                        data: JSON.stringify({
                            ID: code,
                            POS: pos
                        }),
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (response) {

                        }
                    };
                    $x.ajax(options);
                    },
                    receive: function (e, ui) {
                        $x(this).find("tbody").append(ui.item);
                    }
                });
            });
```

Then in the code behind create a webmethod function (please note this was in vb.net, due to restrictions, i am fine if the answer is in c#)

```
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()>
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod>
Public Shared Function MyMethod(ByVal ID As String, ByVal POS As Integer) As String
    Dim a = ID & ", " & POS
    Return ""
End Function
```

now ideally i will have this function get the data and save it to our db, but my main aim here to to get it firing when i debug, hence why the function doesn't really do anything.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's an event called `sortupdate` that fires after the list has been updated. You should be able to put your function in there and it'll fire after.

check out this answer to get you started:

[Call event after sorting in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969945/call-event-after-sorting-in-jquery)